# Setting checkbox to checked using PHP is results in no way to clear the checked attribute after render

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my form which looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="showCTA" name="showCTA" <?php echo $block['showCTA'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
```

Everything works fine with this mark up....unless the PHP value equals 1(already checked). If this is the case, I can check and uncheck the box in the from end visually, but the actual html attribute does not change resulting in the same value of 1 being saved to my database on submit.

How can I work around this in a clean manner? I assume the issue is since the PHP value is absolute until submitted, it means the condition around my "checked" attribute is also absolute, therefore I cannot change the attribute.

Comment: `value` attribute doesn't change on click. It's either posted to server or not. So if it is not posted - your field obviously __not__ updated and remains `1`

Comment: Still have the same issue when removing value="1" @u_mulder

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is not checked and you post the form, the `$_POST['showCTA']` will be undefined. So you should use the `isset($_POST['showCTA'])` method which will return true if the checkbox is checked and if not, false.